# Website alternative to bin folder for assemblies?

Tags: asp.net, web-deployment, .net-assembly

In context of an ASP.NET Website project, is it possible to create a second location where DLLs will be picked up from, in addition to the regular bin/ location and apart from the GAC?  I expect such a feature would be made possible by the configuration.

Comment: Could you explain why you're doing it?

Comment: @IrishChieftain: It's to leverage behavioural characteristics of a deployment model of a particular software application we're combining into our ASP.NET projects. Too much description and noise to bother with here. Just looking to see if Microsoft has provided a way for it to be accomplished, in and of itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`codeBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efs781xb.aspx) element - it allows you to specify URL of an assmebly (which can be a `FILE:` URL), though it does require the assembly to be strongly named.

See [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837908) describing this and another method (using the `AssemblyResolve` event which fires whenever the assembly loader fails to find an assembly).

Comment: I like all this very much. Thank you.